# Azure Devops Repos, sort branches by "authored date"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, branch, azure-repos

In Azure Repos "Branch View" I am able to see a table with branches with their details: Name, Commit, Author, Authored Date, etc. Is there any view which allows me to sort branches by Authored Date? I would like to see on the top of the table the branch which was changed recently.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not supported on Azure DevOps Repos currently.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

Comment: Is there any place with already created requests for issues? Maybe someone already have created it and I can vote it up.

Comment: @fascynacja, you can try to search for some related keywords on [this page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps?ftype=idea) to see whether someone had reported the similar feature request.

Answer (score 2):

I have created an request as suggested by @Bright Ran-MSFT : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Devops-Repos-sort-branches-by-au/10491099. If anyone would like this feature pleae vote it up.

Comment: I have voted it up one.